# Classes containing other classes as properties

Tags: matlab, class, oop

in MATLAB I have different classes `A` & `B`. I want to assign objects created from class `A` & `B` as properties in both `A` & `B` . My code looks like this

```
classdef A < handle

   properties
      container
   end

   methods
      function object = A()
      end
   end
end
```

and this

```
classdef B < handle

   properties
      container
   end

   methods
      function object = B()
      end
   end
end
```

Then I am assigning both objects from class `A` & `B` to the `container`-property from both classes `A` & `B`, like

```
object_from_class_A.container = object_from_class_A
```

and

```
object_from_class_A.container = object_from_class_B
```

This means, I use the same variable/property for storing objects from different classes. Is this a bad design choise? How should I avoid this? I am just trying to assign objects to each other, because I am trying to build relationships between different objects.

P.S. I am new to OOP.

Edit for better explanation:

Class `A` & `B` are fundamentally different and should not be connected/inherited from each other. I have something in mind like this: Object `city` contains object `street` and object `house`, object `house` is connected to object `street`. So, `street` and `house` should inherit from `city`, but `street` and `house` should know each other. But how should I realize the relation between many objects (like sign, car, people, cat, dog, etc) that all inherit from `city` but dont share/inherit anything else between each other?

For example I want to establish a connection beween a `car` an an `street` object, so if I look into a specific `street`-object, I want to assign the specific objects `car1`, `car2`, `car3` to the `street` object.

Comment: If you're assigning objects from both classes to the same variable, what is the difference between the two classes? Are the two classes related (or relatable) by a superclass, or are the two classes fundamentally different but need to share information? As it stands this is not the best design, but I think we need further information about the classes themselves to help.

Comment: The classes A & B are fundamentally different (yes I should be more specific...).

Comment: "`street` and `house` should inherit from `city`".  I disagree.  Those three items are fundamentally different entities, albeit related.  I would say make them their own classes, and have `city` contain, or in OOP terminology "be composed of", `street` arrays and `house` arrays.

Comment: See [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) vs. [Has-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/has-a).

Comment: AH, this is usefull. Thanks! I think I am looking for a "aggregation-relation" (relation without ownership). Do you have an example how to implement this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, you essentially want to emulate a one-to-many relationship between objects.

One possible way of doing this would be to store the handle to the "one" side of the relationship within each of the "many" side's objects and then use something like `findobj` to get the a list of objects that share the same "one" object reference.

In the case of your `Car` and `Street` example.

```
classdef Car < handle
    properties
        name
        street      % A handle to the street you're on
    end

    methods
        function self = Car(name, street)
            self.name = name;
            self.street = street;
        end
    end
end
```

And then your `Street` class

```
classdef Street < handle
    properties
        name
    end

    methods
        function self = Street(name)
            self.name = name;
        end
    end
end
```

And then you could use it like

```
% Create some streets
streets = [Street('Street1'), ...
           Street('Street2')];

% Create some cars
cars = [Car('one', streets(1)), ...
        Car('two', streets(2)), ...
        Car('three', streets(1))];

% Now get cars that are on Street1
cars_on_street_1 = findobj(cars, 'street', streets(1));
```

This has the added advantage in that it is trivial to change streets (since you only have to update the car object)

```
cars(1).street = streets(2);
```

The downside is that you have to maintain a list of `Street` and `Car` objects to pass to `findobj` and this search could potentially get to be a performance bottleneck for a very large number of objects.

Now if you're not going to be changing what street a car is on etc. then you could always create a factory to construct the class relationships (adding references in both objects) and then just *use* the data that you've created.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly here is my suggestion.

Inheritance enable a new class to take on properties and methods of another class. Class B in your case wouldn't need the additional function definition if you have it inherit from class A.

Comment: But class A & B are different and should not be connected. I have something in mind like this: Object `city` contains object `street` and object `house`, object `house` is connected to object `street`. So, `street` and `house` should inherit from `city`, but `street` and `house` should know each other. But how should I realize the relation between many objects that all inherit from `city`?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Please either elaborate on the answer, or delete it altogether, possibly reposting it as a comment once you have 50 reputation.