# MATLAB constructor / interface-class without object

Tags: matlab, class, oop, constructor, interface

is there a way in MATLAB to construct some kind of an use-interface-class or something, that does not output an own object? I have something like this in mind:

```
object1_from_class_main = constructor_class_A()
object2_from_class_main = constructor_class_B()
object3_from_class_main = constructor_class_C()
```

with `class_A` / `class_B` / `class_C` inherit from `class_main`. This means there should exist a `main_class` that handles all user input, and inside of this class, all other subclasses are constructed/maintained.

I dont know if there is a big mistake in this, but would appreciate, if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Why not just use a function to create the classes? Also maybe give us a real world example of *why* you want to do this.

Comment: Well I need something like a base-class, that is able to iterate through all objects, stores their handles etc. This is why I would like to use this base/main-class as interface for the user.

Comment: What was wrong with the method proposed in my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556731/classes-containing-other-classes-as-properties)

Comment: I feel like it would be much easier if you just explained what you're trying to do rather than asking multiple *really* unclear questions about how OOP works.

Comment: It does make sense to have different objects (`chair`, `table`, etc) that are all derived from a superclass (`furniture`), which handles all the common tasks, such as input handling. Note that a `chair` object will show up as class:chair, but it will also be of class:furniture (i.e. `isa(object, 'furniture')` will return `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design, the constructor *must* return an object of the class that the constructor belongs to *or* [the output should be unassigned](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html#bu80qn_). It cannot return an object of a *different* class. From [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html).

> The only output argument from a constructor is the object constructed. If you do not want to assign the output argument, you can clear the object variable in the constructor.

You *could* define a static method for `classA`, `classB`, etc. that returns an object of class `Main`

```
classdef ClassA < handle
    methods (Static)
        function mainobj = create_main()
            % Construct Main object and do whatever you need to here
            mainobj = Main();
        end
    end
end

class_of_main = ClassA.create_main();
```

Alternately, you could make your `Main` instance a property of your classes

```
classdef ClassA < handle

    properties
        mainobj
    end

    methods
        function self = ClassA()
            self.mainobj = Main()
        end
    end
end
```

A better question though is *why* you need to do this.

**Update**

Based on your clarification, you want basically a controller to keep track of all of the `Furniture` objects that you create. You can do this with a class which keeps track of `Furniture` objects

```
classdef FurnitureController < handle
    properties
        furnitures = furniture.empty()
    end

    methods
        function addFurniture(self, furniture)
            self.furnitures = [self.furnitures, furniture];
        end
    end
end

classdef Furniture < handle
end

classdef Chair < Furniture
end

classdef Desk < Furniture
end

controller = FurnitureController()
controller.addFurniture(Desk())
controller.addFurniture(Chair())
```

Comment: Well, I will try to explain why I am trying to do this: The user should be able to generate different objects like `chair`,`table`,`cupboard`. But all of these objects belong to a superclass `furniture`. If the user uses the command `red_chair = chair()` I dont want him to produce an object of class `chair`, but an object of the superclass `furniture`, that handles different functions to all of its child-objects.

Comment: @Lemonbonbon So if the user creates a `chair`, they likely want a `chair` not a `furniture`. You'd be pretty upset if you asked for a `Girlfriend` or `Boyfriend` and I gave you a generic `Person` object wouldn't you? Have you looked at superclasses at all?

Comment: @Suever Can anybody find meeeeee some `Person` to loveee